# What is the geometrical interpretation of Lipschitz condition?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, continuity

A function $f$ is said to satisfy Lipscitz condition on $D$ if there exists $M>0$ such that for every $x_1,x_2$ belonging to $D$ we have $$|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\leq M|x_1-x_2|.$$
Now, what is the geometric interpretation of this thing? Does this mean that slope of chord joining any $2$ points on the curve $y=f(x)$ is bounded. Does this imply that derived function $f'$ of $f$ is bounded on $D$ (provided derivative exists on $D$)? Can it be understood with the help of diagram geometrically? I had heard some concept of double cone for this thing. Can someone explain that, too?

Comment: Edit the necessary places by mathjax.

Comment: It means your function varies within a fixed cone at each point.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar It means that when you consider two points and their images, the distance between images is bounded byb a fixed "multiple" of the distance between the points. For instance, if $M=1$, this means that the distance between images is always smaller than the distance between the points.